# NEW Selenium IDE - how to run and store JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a bunch of old test scripts that were written for the old Selenium IDE. I'm trying to update them to run with the new Selenium, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out what to do with bits of javascript and the new syntax.

For example, I have something like:

(command)STORE   (Target) javascript{Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)}  (Value) ReportNumber

But all Selenium does is store the javascript expression as a variable if I use that old Syntax. I saw that the new IDE wants us to instead use Run Script but I need to run the javascript and save it as a variable and none of the attempts I've made thus far have worked. Has anyone figure out HOW to use and run javascript successfully, and to save it as a variable.  Examples if you have them, please!!

Answer (score 5):

You now need to use the `execute script` command instead, like this:

`execute script | return Math.floor(Math.random()*100000) | ReportNumber`

The "target" of the `execute script` command is the JavaScript to execute, and the "value" is the name of variable you want Selenium to put the result into. The `return` in the JavaScript is not optional!

Comment: Consider editing to add an explanation as to why the OP "should use `execute script ` instead...".